# Mutate across DF to calculate percentage of each column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a pivot table with several referral sources, and data time points

e.g.,

```
         NHS      Private   Other   Sum
Jan      100      100       100     300
Feb      120      80       50      250
March    50       105       400    555
```

How can I use the Sum column to mutate across the DF to create new variables based on the percentage of each column to Sum at that time-point e.g.

```
        NHS    Private    Other     Sum
Jan     33.3%    33.3%     33.3%     100%     **and so on** 
Feb     N%       N%
March   N%
```

Comment: Hello, I have marked your question as a duplicate of an existing question.  If the answers there don't answer your question, please let me know by replying here - and ideally edit your question to clarify its uniqueness.